# jquery select the input inside the selected <tr>

Tags: jquery

Trying to select the input inside the tr previously selected and add focus to it.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="login" style="position:relative; display:none; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; z-index:10;" class="trwhole">
<table width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr width="100%" height="100%">
        <td width="100%" height="100%" style="vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">
            <img src="images/MemorizeItWhite.png" z-index="10000" style="width:290px;">
            <table align="center" class="w290">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="lerror" class="alert"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Username:
                        <br>
                        <input autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" style="" class="ui-corner-all w290">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">Password:
                        <br>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" style="" class="ui-corner-all w290" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13){login();}">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" id="loginBt" onclick="login();" value="Log In" class="submit" style="width:85px;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here's the selector so far:

```
$('#login tr:has(input[placeholder]), #signup2 tr:has(input[placeholder])').on("touchstart", 
function (evt) { $(evt.target).filter("input").focus(); }
);
```

Unfortunately 
    `$(evt.target).filter("input").focus();`
isn't doing it.

I've also tried

```
$(this).filter('input').focus();
```

but the doesn't get focus to the input either.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`evt.target` refers to the element from where the event is originated, it may not be the `tr` element. you can use `this` inside the click handler to refer to the `tr` element

```
$('#login tr:has(input[placeholder]), #signup2 tr:has(input[placeholder])').on("touchstart", function (evt) {
    $(this).find("input").focus();
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bxjSW/)

Comment: I tried that, as noted in my question, except you used double quotes instead of single quotes. I tried it that way just now, but still no luck.

Comment: @K'shin was suppose to use find instead of filter